# Grouping sizes from multiple formats into small, medium, large using R's dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Here's a sample data set:

```
df <- tibble(
  size = c("l", "L/Black", "medium", "small", "large", "L/White", "s", 
       "L/White", "M", "S/Blue", "M/White", "L/Navy", "M/Navy", "S"),
  shirt = c("blue", "black", "black", "black", "white", "white", "purple",
        "white", "purple", "blue", "white", "navy", "navy", "navy")
)
```

The data set above has a column `size`, where it shows the basics: `small`, `medium`, and `large`. But it also has other representations of those sizes, like `M`, or `S/Blue`, or `s`.

I want to use the most efficient way to make everything either `small`, `medium`, or `large`, and get rid of the colors in the `size` category. E.g. equate `L/Black` to just `large`.

I can do this using `gsub` a bunch of times, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way than my initial thought. My data set is several thousand lines long, and the following example of code sucks to write:

```
df$size <- df$size %>%
 gsub("M", "medium", .) %>%
 gsub("mediumedium", "medium", .) %>%
 gsub("S", "small", .) %>%
 gsub("smallmall", "small", .) %>%
 gsub("L", "large", .) %>%
 gsub("S/Blue", "small", .) %>%
 gsub("L/Navy", "large", .)
```

This method doesn't work well, as it introduces things like `smallmall`, or `mediumedium` when running through the first two `gsub`'s above. What's the best way to standardize everything in the three main sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  # Remove color
  mutate(size = map2_chr(size, shirt, ~str_replace(.x, fixed(.y, ignore_case = TRUE), ""))) %>%
  # Remove /
  mutate(size = str_replace(size, fixed("/"), "")) %>%
  # Replacement
  mutate(size = case_when(
    size %in% "l" | size %in% "L"    ~ "large",
    size %in% "m" | size %in% "M"    ~ "medium",
    size %in% "s" | size %in% "S"    ~ "small",
    TRUE                             ~ size
  ))
df2
# # A tibble: 14 x 2
#    size   shirt 
#    <chr>  <chr> 
#  1 large  blue  
#  2 large  black 
#  3 medium black 
#  4 large  black 
#  5 large  white 
#  6 large  white 
#  7 small  purple
#  8 large  white 
#  9 medium purple
# 10 small  blue  
# 11 medium white 
# 12 large  navy  
# 13 medium navy  
# 14 small  navy
```

Comment: I think you need more specific regex. Compare the original sizes to the ones in your `case_when`—`"l|L"` will turn up positive for `"small"` as well as the "large" variants you're trying to catch

Comment: Your first one worked (though, I have no idea if there were match errors), but the second version doesn't work - it removed the `/` and the space in the `L/Black` type of sizes to look like `LBlack`

Comment: @papelr My solution works fine on my machine. I could not reproduce the behavior you mentioned. No any `LBlack` on my final output.

Answer (score 1):

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>%
  # Extract the alphanum substring at the start of "size"
  extract(size, "size2", regex = "^(\\w*)", remove = FALSE) %>%
  # All lowercase in case there are sizes like "Small"
  # And then recode as required.
  # Here "l" = "large" means take all occurrences of "l" and
  # recode them as "large", etc.
  mutate(size3 = recode(tolower(size2),
                        "l" = "large",
                        "m" = "medium",
                        "s" = "small"))
# # A tibble: 14 x 4
#   size    size2  shirt  size3
#   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 l       l      blue   large
# 2 L/Black L      black  large
# 3 medium  medium black  medium
# 4 small   small  black  small
# 5 large   large  white  large
```

Of course you don't need three size columns. I used different column names so that it is obvious what each transformation achieves.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. The OP said "make everything either small, medium, or large".

Comment: Thanks, @www, I've fixed the mapping to the final categories.